# Collection view content not showing in view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, swift5

I have no idea why this is happening, I had a different Xcode project with this exact same collection view just to test things out and make it and I've finished making it and it works very well in that project. Then I moved all the code and items over to my main Xcode project and the collection view just isn't showing in my view controller when I play the app.

How do you debug collection views? The two: `playerCollect?.cellForItem(at: path)` and `playerCollect.indexPathForItem(at: p)` both return nil if that's an issue? I don't know. I might've not connected everything back together once I moved it over to my main project, but yet again how would you find that out? Here's my full code for the viewController containing the UICollectionView:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Firebase
import MMPlayerView


class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var offsetObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    lazy var mmPlayerLayer: MMPlayerLayer = {
    let l = MMPlayerLayer()
    l.cacheType = .memory(count: 5)
    l.coverFitType = .fitToPlayerView
    l.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    l.replace(cover: CoverA.instantiateFromNib())
    l.repeatWhenEnd = true
    return l
}()

@IBOutlet weak var playerCollect: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // remove previous download fails file
    MMPlayerDownloader.cleanTmpFile()
    self.navigationController?.mmPlayerTransition.push.pass(setting: { (_) in

    })
    offsetObservation = playerCollect.observe(\.contentOffset, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (_, value) in
        guard let self = self, self.presentedViewController == nil else {return}
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
        self.perform(#selector(self.startLoading), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.2)
    }
    playerCollect.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 200, right:0)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { [weak self] in
        self?.updateByContentOffset()
        self?.startLoading()
    }

        mmPlayerLayer.getStatusBlock { [weak self] (status) in
            switch status {
            case .failed(let err):
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "err", message: err.description, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            case .ready:
                print("Ready to Play")
            case .playing:
                print("Playing")
            case .pause:
                print("Pause")
            case .end:
                print("End")
            default: break
            }
        }
        mmPlayerLayer.getOrientationChange { (status) in
            print("Player OrientationChange \(status)")
        }
    }

deinit {
    offsetObservation?.invalidate()
    offsetObservation = nil
    print("ViewController deinit")
}

@IBAction func profileButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let uid = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
    let Splash = SpalshScreenViewController()
    Splash.GetProfilePicture(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetUsername(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetName(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetClipsNumber(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetFollowersNumber(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetFollowingsNumber(uid: uid)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showProfile", sender: nil)
}
}

extension HomeViewController: MMPlayerFromProtocol {
     func backReplaceSuperView(original: UIView?) -> UIView? {
        guard let path = self.findCurrentPath(),
            let cell = self.findCurrentCell(path: path) as? PlayerCell else {
            return original
    }
    return cell.imgView
}

// add layer to temp view and pass to another controller
var passPlayer: MMPlayerLayer {
    return self.mmPlayerLayer
}
func transitionWillStart() {
}
// show cell.image
func transitionCompleted() {
    self.updateByContentOffset()
    self.startLoading()
}
}
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let m = min(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    return CGSize(width: m, height: m*0.75)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
    if self.presentedViewController != nil || self.mmPlayerLayer.isShrink == true {
            //self.playerCollect.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
            //self.updateDetail(at: indexPath)
        } else {
            self.presentDetail(at: indexPath)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func updateByContentOffset() {
    if mmPlayerLayer.isShrink {
        return
    }

    if let path = findCurrentPath(),
        self.presentedViewController == nil {
        self.updateCell(at: path)
        //Demo SubTitle
        if path.row == 0, self.mmPlayerLayer.subtitleSetting.subtitleType == nil {
            let subtitleStr = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "srtDemo", ofType: "srt")!
            if let str = try? String.init(contentsOfFile: subtitleStr) {
                self.mmPlayerLayer.subtitleSetting.subtitleType = .srt(info: str)
                self.mmPlayerLayer.subtitleSetting.defaultTextColor = .red
                self.mmPlayerLayer.subtitleSetting.defaultFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func presentDetail(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.updateCell(at: indexPath)
    mmPlayerLayer.resume()

    if let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController {
        vc.data = DemoSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row]
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

fileprivate func updateCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = playerCollect.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PlayerCell, let playURL = cell.data?.play_Url {
        // this thumb use when transition start and your video dosent start
        mmPlayerLayer.thumbImageView.image = cell.imgView.image
        // set video where to play
        mmPlayerLayer.playView = cell.imgView
        mmPlayerLayer.set(url: playURL)
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func startLoading() {
    self.updateByContentOffset()
    if self.presentedViewController != nil {
        return
    }
    // start loading video
    mmPlayerLayer.resume()
}

private func findCurrentPath() -> IndexPath? {
    let p = CGPoint(x: playerCollect.contentOffset.x + playerCollect.frame.width/2, y: playerCollect.frame.height/2)
print(playerCollect.indexPathForItem(at: p))
    return playerCollect.indexPathForItem(at: p)
}

private func findCurrentCell(path: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell? {
    print(playerCollect?.cellForItem(at: path))
   return playerCollect?.cellForItem(at: path)
}
}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DemoSource.shared.demoData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {
        cell.data = DemoSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
}
```

Comment: check your `UICollectionView ` delegate and data source? Have you connect it from the storyboard?

Comment: @HardikS how would I do that could I do it from the swift file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you give the collection view's delegate and data source at this view controller?

```
self.playerCollect.delegate = self
self.playerCollect.dataSource = self
```

and add:

```
self.playerCollect.reloadData()
```

Comment: how would I do that could I do it from the swift file?

Comment: at ViewDidLoad : playerCollect.dataSource = self and playerCollect.delegate = self and playerCollect.reloadData()

Comment: and your class should be : class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource

Comment: that's the weird thing, I didn't need to set them two in my previous project for it to work, I'm guessing it's just a simple connection?

Comment: I shouldn't need to do that in my class as I have extensions to do that

Comment: Even you have extensions, you must give delegate and datasource's to your class.

Comment: @Picode please give answer how to set delegate and datasource, However you are asking a question to him.

Comment: @Picode I controlled dragged my collectionView to my view controller to add the delegate and datasource and now I'm getting an error in my Data structure class `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1d409678c)`

Comment: @Daljeet, self.playerCollect.delegate = self
       self.playerCollect.dataSource = self

Comment: @NathanEllis, I thank best way is: doing this at ViewControllerClass. self.playerCollect.delegate = self self.playerCollect.dataSource = self

Comment: @Picode what you are telling in comments it should be in your answer so please edit your answer.

Comment: @Picode yes, edit your answer so I can mark it as an answer since that was what I was missing, didn't realise you could control drag the delegate and datasource

Comment: Yes Hope I helped you.

Comment: @NathanEllis Happy coding:)

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as below.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

               self.playerCollect.delegate = self
               self.playerCollect.dataSource = self
    }
}


extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DemoSource.shared.demoData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {
            cell.data = DemoSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```